# Interaction of 2 armatures with each other

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

Please, could you say how to do so that 2 armatures interact with each other? For example, one character takes the hand of the other one & pulls it with it. But as you can see, the hand of the second character doesn't follow the trajectory of the first one.

If the bone of one hand is tied to the bone of the other hand, it will repeat the trajectory, but the mesh will stretch, not follow the selected bone. If try to fit keyframes, the different location of the keyframes will not allow this to be done correctly (the result you see on the example).

Please please please, help me with this question!

[image]

Comment: have you tried to give a Child Of constraint to the hand bone? and you only activate its influence when needed

Comment: Yes, I tried modifier Child Of, but probably I do something wrong because I don't get need result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QVwL.gif

Comment: perhaps share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This is my usual variant of the bones settings + I tried to add Child of, but it didn't work out what I wanted. Keep a sample, maybe you'll see what I'm doing wrong. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5143" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5143/)

Comment: I think your rigging is not correct, you must parent the hand bone to the lower arm controller, so that when you rotate your controller the hand follow, otherwise it's very uneasy to control the hand properly

Comment: OK, I changed the settings of the hand bone & it worked. But now there is a small problem. How to make it so that mesh doesn't stretch? https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFHQn.gif

Comment: Try this: give your hand a Copy Location constraint, with the lower arm as the Target, a Head/Tail > 1, and stay in Space > World Space. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you sooooo much for your help!!! You're very well versed in rigging & you really helped me. Can I ask one more question, please? Is it possible to adjust the bones so that not only the arm moves with the object, but the whole body (I mean that the body also tilts to the direction where the object is pulling)? Or is it still necessary to move each bone separately (for example, root, spine)?

Comment: yes I guess you have to move the whole body, but maybe you should describe a little bit more the action

Comment: maybe an information that could help you: If you character catch an object, his hand bone can become Child Of the object so that when you move the object you also move the arme of the character. Also, there is an addon called Dynamic Parent that makes it even easy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJaJ4_O8MJg#t=04m15s

Comment: Yeah, I know about Dynamic parent. Cool thing. It really helps in creating animations. But that's not exactly what I meant. OK, I'll try to explain. For example, when one character takes the second character's hand & leads somewhere, that moves only the second character's hand. The body itself remains motionless. I.e. it doesn't bend & not following the hand.

Comment: if the controller of the second character becomes child of the hand of the first, automatically the hand of the second will follow, but yes, not the whole body. But perhaps ask a new question to see if someone has a better answer  ;)

Comment: OK, I understood. Thank you again for that you helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parent the *hand* bone to the *lower arm* controller, so that when you rotate your controller the hand follow, otherwise it's very uneasy to control the hand properly.

Also, give your hand a *Copy Location* constraint, with the *lower arm* as the *Target*, a *Head/Tail* > 1, and stay in *Space* > *World Space*.

[image]